# Java EE, GWT, NoClassDefException

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I have an app, built on GWT (google web toolkit) and JPA (eclipselink 2.3). it's not using GAE (app engine).

when I finished application, I ran 'google->gwt compile' menu in eclipse and then uploaded /war content to the tomcat directory...

application is running, but when I try to do one specific action in gui, I get an error message and Tomcat log contains this exception: http://paste2.org/p/1879857 (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

during development of the application, I encountered this kind of exception several times, it was always caused by absence of library .jar file in the war/WEB-INF/lib/...  anytime it has occurred, I stored .jar to the folder and it worked... but not this time...

this class is located in gwt-dev.jar (yes, it is there - have searched the archive) and it didn't help me to store archive to the lib/ folder...

it is also included in classpath, and compiler had no problem... compilation finished without errors (so compiler can see the class).

do you have any idea, how to make tomcat to see the class?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gwt-dev.jar` shouldn't be in `WEB-INF/lib/`, it is the GWT compiler, and shouldn't be needed or used at runtime. At the same time, that HashSet (`com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashSet`, part of dev mode) shouldn't be used outside the compiler - use `java.util.HashSet` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `HashSet` import in `GroupImpl.java` from `com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashSet` to `java.util.HashSet`. You shouldn't need `gwt-dev.jar` to run your application.